# Express multiple delete routes

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

I am using the MEAN stack with sequelize. I have two cases where I want to delete records from a table:

1) delete a single record using an given id.

2) delete all records where some condition is met (all records that share a projectId). For this to work I am trying to set up two routes to handle each case.

Client side service (case 1):

```
  this.deleteCampaign = function(id) {
    return $http.delete(campaignBaseUrl + id);
  };
```

Client side service (case 2):

```
  this.deleteMultipleCampaigns = function(projectID) {
    return $http.delete(campaignBaseUrl+ 'foo/' + projectID);
  };
```

Server side routes:

```
// I want case 1 to access this route (working)
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);
// I want case 2 to access this route (not working)
router.delete('/foo/:projectID', controller.destroyMultiple);
```

**UPDATE** 
Server side controllers:

```
// Deletes multiple Campaign from the DB
// for a give project ID
export function destroyMultiple(req, res) {
  console.log('req.params:');
  console.log(req.params); // { projectID: '7' }
  Campaign.findAll({
    where: {
      projectId: req.params.projectID
    }
  })
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(removeEntity(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}

// Deletes a single Campaign from the DB
export function destroy(req, res) {
  console.log('destroySingle:');
  Campaign.find({
    where: {
      _id: req.params.id
    }
  })
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(removeEntity(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Server side controller cont...

```
function removeEntity(res) {
  return function(entity) {
    if (entity) {
      return entity.destroy()
        .then(() => {
          res.status(204).end();
        });
    }
  };
}
```

When I run case2 from the client I get this error:
`DELETE /api/campaigns/foo/7 500`
and
`{"name":"SequelizeDatabaseError","message":"invalid input syntax for integer: \"foo\"","parent":`

Comment: Maybe 'foo' was passed into your db query instead of 58.  how does `destroyMultiple` unpack the parameter?

Comment: I thought the same and used this to check the id parameter:

```router.param('id', function (req, res, next, id) {  
  console.log('id:');
  console.log(id);
  next();
});```
The id is correctly passed

Comment: Are you sure the correct handler is being called for that request (ie `destroyMultiple`)?

Comment: It should be `projectID` not `id` so maybe it is actually calling the :id route.

Comment: @leetibbett I am not sure I understand, the `projectId` and the `id` are both integers, how can they determine the routing?

Comment: @robertklep I think this is the crux of the matter, I am not sure how this can be don correctly when one has multiple DELETE routes?

Comment: @Bwyss add a different `console.log()` to each controller method and see which one gets logged.

Comment: @robertklep, the `destroyMultiple` controller method is getting logged with: `req.params: { projectID: '65' }`

Comment: @Bwyss in that case, I think your controller implementation may be the problem. Are you passing `req.params` instead of `req.params.projectID` into the Sequelize query?

Comment: @robertklep I am using `req.params.projectID` in the controller. In the terminal output I can see it executing the select: `SELECT "_id", "projectId", ... FROM "campaigns" AS "campaigns" WHERE "campaigns"."projectId" = '7';` which is a valid query. But then just under that line I get `DELETE /api/campaigns/foo/7 500 73.201 ms - 2`

Comment: @Bwyss hmm that doesn't really make sense. Does the stack trace of the error provide any clues where that failing query is being run?

Comment: @robertklep the failing query is coming from the server side controller line `.then(removeEntity(res))` (see the update to the question for context)

Comment: something called `/foo`

Comment: `.find()` returns _one_ result, `.findAll()` returns _multiple_ results, so `removeEntity()` needs to be able to deal with that. Can it?

Comment: @Plato I'm going to assume that it's not _that_ easy ;D

Comment: @robertklep I included the removeEntity function as another update to the question

Comment: @robertklep you are right, I think I need to loop through the entity array and destroy each record where there is a match, thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @robertklep for helping me identify the issue. I thought it was with the routing, but instead the issue was in the server side controller method. I revised it to this:

```
// Deletes multiple Campaign from the DB
// for a give project ID
export function destroyMultiple(req, res) {
  Campaign.destroy({
    where: {
      projectId: req.params.projectID
    }
  })
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(() => {
      res.status(204).end();
    })
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The express.js documentation states

> The order of middleware loading is important: middleware functions
>   that are loaded first are also executed first.

That means that in your current router configuration

```
// I want case 1 to access this route (working)
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);
// I want case 2 to access this route (not working)
router.delete('/foo/:projectID', controller.destroyMultiple);
```

the first route matches the url /api/campaigns/foo/7 too. It does not matter if the second route matches the url better. The first route captures 'foo/7' or 'foo' as the parameter `:id`. Either way, the value is not an integer.

I suppose the field `campaign.projectId` is an integer and **boooooom**: The Sequelize error is thrown.

### Possible Solution

Put the more specific routes first. Like so:

```
router.delete('/foo/:projectID', controller.destroyMultiple);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);
```